# Kendo datasource shema.data does not work for dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, odata

I have Odata WebApi, and I want to populate my dropdownlist with data from there.
I have datasource:

`var postsDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                type: 'odata',
                serverFiltering: true,
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "/odata/Posts",
                        dataType: "json"
                    },
                },
                schema: {
                    model: kendo.data.Model.define({
                        Id: "Id",
                        RegionId: "RegionId"
                    }),
                    data: function (res) {
                        debugger;//this code is inaccessible! 
                        console.log(res);
                        return res.value;
                    }
                },
            });`

and dropdownlist like this:

```
var posts = $("#searchPost").kendoDropDownList({
            optionLabel: "Выберите регион...",
            dataTextField: "NameRu",
            dataValueField: "Id",
            dataSource: postsDataSource,
        }).data("kendoDropDownList");
```

This part of code executes odata query and return me the following json response in the firebug's console:

```
{
  "odata.metadata":"http://localhost:11029/odata/$metadata#Posts","odata.count":"13","value":[
    {
      "Id":0,"Number":"Lenina45","RegionId":1,"NameRu":"\u041b\u0435\u043d\u0438\u043d\u0430 45","NameKz":"\u041b\u0435\u043d\u0438\u043d\u0430 45","ShortName":"\u041b\u0435\u043d\u0438\u043d\u0430 45","DateBegin":null,"DateEnd":null,"OptimisticLockField":null
    },{
      "Id":1,"Number":"Zhumabaeva15","RegionId":2,"NameRu":"\u0416\u0443\u043c\u0430\u0431\u0430\u0435\u0432\u0430 15","NameKz":"\u0416\u0443\u043c\u0430\u0431\u0430\u0435\u0432\u0430 15","ShortName":"\u0416\u0443\u043c\u0430\u0431\u0430\u0435\u0432\u0430 15","DateBegin":null,"DateEnd":null,"OptimisticLockField":null
    },
    .....
  ]
}
```

Right after this response I am getting the following strange error:

**TypeError: d.d is undefined;**
And dropdownlist doesn't show me above json response.
When I populated kendo grid with odata web api, the following code in datasource solved my problem:

```
schema: {
                    data: function (res) {
                        return res.value;
                    }
                },
```

but now, when I use it for dropdownlist it doesn't work at all, it's inaccessible.

*PS> Sorry for my bad English.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Data Is on the inner object "value" on your response , your response consist on page size , metadata url so we need to prase the data that kendo dataSource can understand here is a exsample

: Note Remove "type: 'odata'" and check , since you are saying the dataSource where the Data is from the Data function no need of it as I think.

```
var postsDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                serverFiltering: true,
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "/odata/Posts",
                        dataType: "json"
                    },
                },
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        Id: "Id",
                         fields: {
                           Id: { type: "number" },
                           NameRu: { type: "string" },
                            NameKz: { type: "string"},
                            ShortName: { type: "string" }
                        }
                    },
                    data: function (response) {
                        return response.value;
                    },
                    total: function(response) {
                     return response.odata.count; 
                     }
                },
            });
```

try this hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I've just added this `total: function(response) {
                     return response.odata.count; 
                     }` from your sample, and it works for me. I use "type:'odata'" to be able to apply server filtering for cascade dropdowns.